# RIP Michael Anderson, famed director of Logan's Run

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Michael Anderson, the British director who was nominated for an Academy Award for his direction on “Around the World in 80 Days,” and who won a Special Academy Award for *innovative special effects* for "Logan's Run", has died at the age of 98.

His filmography includes a host of iconic hit films including The Dambusters, 1984, Doc Savage and The Shoes of the Fisherman.